# Codifying presence/absence of authentication at type level

Tags: haskell, yesod

**Context:** I'm approaching Haskell from a standpoint of converting runtime errors to compile-time errors. My hypothesis is that this is possible if one can codify business logic within the program's types itself.

I'm writing a Telegram bot, which should be accessible by users within my company. To achieve this "restriction", whenever someone starts chatting with the bot it will look up the `chat_id` in a table and check if a valid `oauth_token` exists. If not, the user will first be sent a link to complete a Google OAuth (our company's email is hosted on Google Apps for Business).

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
VLUser
  email String
  chatId Integer
  tgramUserId Integer
  tgramFirstName String
  tgramLastName String Maybe
  tgramUsername String Maybe
  oauthToken String Maybe
  deriving Show
|]
```

Users with a valid `oauth_token` will be able to give the Telegram bot some commands, which unauthenticated users should not be able to give.

Now, I'm trying to codify this logic at the type level itself. There will be some functions in my Haskell code that will have the ability to accept, as arguments, both, authenticated & unauthenticated users; while some functions should accept only authenticated users.

If I keep passing user objects of the same type, i.e. `VLUser` everywhere, then I will have to be careful to check for the presence of `oauthToken` in every function. Is there a way to create two user types - `VLUser` and `VLUserAuthenticated` where:

1. Both map to the same underlying table
2. A `VLUserAuthenticated` can be instantiated ONLY IF it has an `oauthToken`

Comment: This seems similar to the problem of a mutex. You want to specify at the type level whether the function requires the lock or not. You can see one possible way to deal with this [here](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#indexed-monads) look at the `IState` type. Replace `Locked` and `Unlocked` with `Authenticated` and `UnAuthenticated` and provide the user a `login` function that checks for the `oauth` token and which is the only way to obtain an `Authenticated` value.

Answer (score 8):

[**Phantom types to the rescue!**](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/11au-cs240h/notes/laziness.html#phantom-types-to-the-rescue) is Bryan O'Sullivan example of implementing read-only vs read/write access **at the type level** using [**phantom types**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type).

Similarly, for your use-case:

```
data Unknown       -- unknown users
data Authenticated -- verified users

newtype User a i = Id i deriving Show
```

It is *important* that the data constructor `Id` is *not* exposed to user, but the module provides functions to initialize and authenticate users:

```
-- initializes an un-authenticated user
newUser :: i -> User Unknown i
newUser = Id

-- authenticates a user
authUser :: (User a i) -> User Authenticated i
authUser (Id i) = Id i  -- dummy implementation
```

then, you may control access at the type level *without code duplication*, *without run-time checks* and *without run-time cost*:

```
-- open to all users
getId :: User a i -> i
getId (Id i) = i

-- only authenticated users can pass through
getId' :: User Authenticated i -> i
getId' (Id i) = i
```

For example, if

```
\> let jim = newUser "jim"
\> let joe = authUser $ newUser "joe"
```

`joe` is an authenticated user and can be passed to either function:

```
\> getId joe
"joe"
\> getId' joe
"joe"
```

whereas, you will get *compile-time error* if you call `getId'` with `jim`:

```
\> getId jim
"jim"
\> getId' jim   -- compile-time error! not run-time error!

<interactive>:28:8:
    Couldn't match type ‘Unknown’ with ‘Authenticated’
    Expected type: User Authenticated [Char]
      Actual type: User Unknown [Char]
    In the first argument of ‘getId'’, namely ‘jim’
    In the expression: getId' jim
```

Comment: While this seems like a workable solution, is this the only approach? It just __seems__ like a lot of boiler-plate for something that can easily be solved by inheritance in other languages.

Comment: If this boilerplate is necessary, is there a macro which can convert this into a one-liner?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda i do not agree! it is actually the other way around: no code to do run time checks and no duplicated code to implement same logic across user types