# Authentication with user roles

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

Is there a way (or a library) to allow user roles? Something like `requreUser "ADMINS" ...` or `requireUser "USERS" ...`.

Or do I have to implement this myself?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246397